# Error config.vm.boot_timeout en vagrant up para Homestead

Tags: laravel-5, laravel, vagrant

Estuve trabajando con Homestead bastante tiempo. Hace unos dias, borro ubuntu por que tenia varios problemas de inestabilidad, cambio a mint con la promesa de ser un poco mas estable y me salta este error.. Pensando que tenia algun problema en la distro, volvi a Ubuntu Mate. Pero el error resulta que persiste

Vi que alguien propuso un problema similar en es.stack pero no profundizaron mucho. Asique decidi abrir este.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Encontre varias soluciones, como entrar al gui de vagrant (cosa que puedo hacer) y cambiar los puertos y algunas otras configuraciones sin resultados

La que mas sugieren es la de cambiar el valor de "config.vm.boot_timeout" en el VagrantFile a 600. Pero la verdad es que mi vagrantfile no es igual al que proponen y no aparece esta variable. Asi que no se como agregarla:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION ||= "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("~/.homestead")

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.require_version '>= 1.8.4'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
if File.exist? aliasesPath then
    config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
end

if File.exist? homesteadYamlPath then
    settings = YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath))
elsif File.exist? homesteadJsonPath then
    settings = JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath))
end

Homestead.configure(config, settings)

if File.exist? afterScriptPath then
    config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath, privileged: false
end

if defined? VagrantPlugins::HostsUpdater
    config.hostsupdater.aliases = settings['sites'].map { |site| site['map'] }
end
end
```

Intente destruirla, volver a crear y nada. Me quedaria probar una version mas vieja de vagrant. No recuerdo cual tenia antes.

vagrant version: 1.8.7
vbox version: 5.0.24

Alguna solucion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El archivo Vagrantfile no es más que un archivo de Ruby y lo que Vagrant hace al final de cargar las configuraciones es mezclarlas todas (las de la máquina virtual y sus overrides como este de Homestead).

En ese orden de ideas puedes poner la línea de configuración en cualquier parte que no sea dentro de un condicional o similar, tal vez antes que sea incluido el script de configuración de Homestead (no es más que otro archivo Ruby).

```
config.vm.boot_timeout = 600

Homestead.configure(config, settings)
```

---

Si utilizas Vagrant 1.8.7, al parecer debes usar Virtualbox 5.1+, el cual funciona con Vagrant 1.8.4+

Si usas una versión de Vagrant inferior a 1.8.4, deberás usar Virtualbox 5.0.x

Comment: Lo probe. En definitiva alarga el time que demora el booteo pero al terminar queda en lo mismo. supongo q asi ponga 1000. dara el mismo problema

Comment: di con la solución. tenia una corazonada de que era un tema de incompatibilidades (por eso puse las versiones de ambos en el post). Y jugando comprobe efectivamente lo era. Con vagrant 1.8.7 solo anda con 5.1.x. Para Vbox menores a 5, necesitas Vagrant menos a 1.8.4. Edita la respuesta así te doy el aceptado y no tengo q esperar 2 dias para poner la respuesta

Comment: Con razón, también utilizo 5.0.x , ¿asumo que quisiste decir "Vbox menores a 5.1" ?